# Integral $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{a^2 \cos(nx)}{(a^2 + x^2)^2} dx$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

#### Question

For $a > 0$ and any $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, what is the value of
$$
c_n := \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{a^2}{(a^2 + x^2)^2} \cos(nx) dx?
$$

#### My Attempt

**CORRECTION**
Letting $f_a(x) := \frac{a^2}{(a^2 + x^2)^2}$ for any $a>0$, we can compute that the Fourier transform of $f_a$ is given by
$$
\hat{f}_a(\xi) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_a(x) e^{i \xi x} dx =\frac{\pi}{2a}(1+a|\xi|)e^{-|\xi|a} \qquad \forall \xi \in \mathbb{R}.
$$

Well, if we let $\chi_{b}(x):=\cases{1 & $x\in[-b,b]$\\ 0 & otherwise}$ for any $b > 0$, we also know that
$$
\begin{align}
\hat{\chi}_{b}(\xi) &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \chi_{b}(x) e^{i\xi x} dx\\
&= \int_{-b}^{b} e^{i\xi x} dx\\
&= \frac{1}{i\xi}\left(e^{ib\xi} - e^{-ib\xi}\right)\\
&= \frac{2\sin(b\xi)}{\xi} = 2b\, \text{sinc}(b\xi).
\end{align}
$$
Furthermore, letting $g_b(\xi) := 2b\, \text{sinc}(bx)$, we can see that for $x\in\mathbb{R}$, by the Fourier inversion theorem, the inverse Fourier transform of $g_b$ is
$$
\begin{align}
\check{g}_b(x) &:= \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g_b(\xi) e^{-i\xi x} d\xi = \chi_{b}(x).
\end{align}
$$

Returning back to our original question, we see that for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$
$$
\begin{align}
c_n &= \text{Re}\left[\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_a(x) \chi_{\pi}(x)e^{inx} dx\right] \\
&= \text{Re}\left[\widehat{f_a \chi_{\pi}}(n)\right]\\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi}\text{Re}\left[(\hat{f}_a \ast \hat{\xi}_{\pi})(n)\right]
\end{align}
$$
where $\ast$ denotes the convolution between two functions

> i.e. (brief description) for two functions $f,g$
> $$
> (f\ast g)(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(y) g(x-y) dy = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x-y) g(y) dy
> $$

**NOTE: There was an error in an initial calculation which rendered the other work incorrect. See history of post to see other work.**

Comment: Using WA I found that $$
\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{\cos(nx)}{a^2+x^2}\mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{2a}\left[\left(\mathrm{Si}(nia-n\pi) -\mathrm{Si}(nia+n\pi)\right)\sinh(na) - i\left(\mathrm{Ci}(nia-n\pi) -\mathrm{Ci}(nia+n\pi)\right)\cosh(na)\right]
$$
and differentiating the above equation W.R.T. $a$ leads to an expression for your desired integral (although very long and ugly looking). I strongly suspect you can't get a simpler expression than something like this.

Comment: @RobertLee I see, thank you for looking into that. I am wondering whether simple expressions exist for the case when $n$ is an integer. Or at east a nice expression for its dominant terms. I have made a little more progress above, and it seems that there may be a nice ish expression.